# How to import results of T-SQL query files into script area?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I want to use results of my other queries which are long in new scripts. If I write all of their codes in one script, it would be messy to manage and read the script,besides they would not be reusable. For example I want two join two query results each of them stored in a `.sql` file. I tried this code by enabling `SQLCMD` mode but it does not works:

```
select * from 
:r $(path)\monthly_performance.sql a
inner join 
(select * from 
:r $(path)\ratios_values.sql ) b
on a.symbol=b.symbol
```

Comment: Encapsulate your queries using inline-table-valued functions or just views

Comment: I don't know about this method, would you explain by an example how should I change my queries?

Comment: `select * from dbo.function1() f1 join dbo.function2() f2 on f1.key = f2.key`

Comment: And How to change my queries into function1 and function2?

Comment: Show what is in the `.sql` files, as Stu said, you could just convert these to views or functions.

Comment: `CREATE VIEW YourView AS SELECT ....`

Comment: @Charlieface what is the difference between view and function?

Comment: A view just acts like a table so you do `SELECT * FROM YourSchema.YourView` whereas a Table Valued function normally takes parameters and you call it like this `SELECT * FROM YourSchema.YourFunction(someValueHere)`

Comment: If view acts like a table what is it advantage over using table itself?

Comment: [https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-views/](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-views/)